# Python script for select by attribute function for QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, select-by-attribute

The following is of course working, selects these features of my_layer that have attribute 1 for my_field2 and appends the corresponding attributes of my_field1 in my_list:

```
my_layer = iface.activeLayer()
indexmf = my_layer.fieldNameIndex("my_field1")
my_list = []

it = my_layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression ( u'"my_field2" = 1') )
my_layer.setSelectedFeatures( [ f.id() for f in it ] )
selection = my_layer.selectedFeatures()
for feature in selection:
    sfeat = feature.attributes()[indexmf]
    my_list.append(sfeat)

#and of course remove selection
layer.removeSelection()
```

Then, I would like to create a function to do the above:

[edited.. it is working]

```
def my_function(layer, list, fieldname, attribute, index):
    it = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression ( u'"%s" = {0}'.format(attribute) %fieldname ) ) 
    layer.setSelectedFeatures( [ f.id() for f in it ] )
    selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
    for feature in selection:
        sfeat = feature.attributes()[index]
        list.append(sfeat)
    layer.removeSelection()
```

But when I call it nothing happens:

```
my_function(my_layer, my_list, "my_field2", 1, indexmf)
```

Could you please help me understand what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your function does not work since you put your attributes into the string in the filter expression, which is why Python does not allocate the value you assign to it.

Replace this line

`it = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression ( u'"fieldname" = attribute' ) )`

with

`it = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression ( u'"%s" = '+str(attribute) % fieldname ) )`

Comment: I get an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'str' ,   but I then modified it a little bit more like this: it = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression ( u'"%s" = {0}'.format(attribute) %fieldname ) )  , and finally it is working... thank you for your help!!

Comment: I was assuming that you were passing a string to the filter. If you wish to directly pass an integer you can replace %s (string) with %d (numeric or decimal)

Comment: Even like this (%d) I get the same error.. Also tried your first expression (%s) with another field that has string values and then I get this error: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Indeed I got confused there: you need to cast your attribute to a string by using str(attribute). Otherwise Python will not be able to concatenate the string with the attribute. Another way to do it would be `u'"%s" = %d'% (fieldname,attribute) `

Comment: there seems to be a syntax error.. SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

The number of parameters are different in the function definition and the function call, so your filter expression will filter nothing, because it will substiture indexmf into attribute in your function and index will be undefined.

I suppose your code would be clearer if your function would return the result list. For example

`def my_function(layer, fieldname, attribute, index):
    list = []
    ...
    list.append(...)
    return list`

and calling the function:

`mylist += my_function(....)`

Comment: yes you are right about the number of arguments, but this was only a mistake when posting my question.. I just edited it to correct it.. also I had tried the    return list     argument just did not post it.. but thank you anyway!!